# REST API access: JS and Python code does the job, but Qt/C++ can't. Why?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, wireshark

I am writing a client to work with a python server working in a local network. I think the server's code is irrelevant to show here because it's working as expected (tested with clients written in JavaScript and Python  ... and [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)).

**Problem: client written in Qt/C++ is not working as expected. Response body is always empty.**

**Server**.

For my particular request, the server responds with Error code 500 and a body in format: `{ "message" : "error reason" }`.

[**Wireshark**](https://www.wireshark.org/). I used this tool to be sure about number of request and check response bodies. In all the cases, responses had expected bodies.

**Qt/C++ client.**

Qt client is written in a simple, very standard Qt way:

```
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
                [](QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QByteArray response = reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << "Response body:" << response;
    if (reply->error())
        qDebug() << "System error msg:" << reply->errorString();
    else
        qDebug() << "Success!";
});

qDebug() << "Sending IrsInit request:";
QString initApi = "http://192.168.101.127:1122/api/v1/replay/initReplay";
QUrl url = QUrl(initApi);
QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/json"));
QJsonObject bodyObj
{
    { "game_id", "5c0768177fb8217354de84d0" },
    { "objects", QJsonArray{
            QJsonObject{ {"id", "5c0768207fb8217354de84d1"}, {"name", "Demon"} }
        }
    }
};
QJsonDocument *doc = new QJsonDocument(bodyObj);
qDebug() << "url:" << url.toString() << "\nbody:" << doc->toJson();

manager->post(request, doc->toJson());
```

*Here is the output:*

```
Sending IrsInit request:
url: "http://192.168.101.127:1122/api/v1/replay/initReplay" 
body: "{"game_id": "5c0768177fb8217354de84d0", "objects": [{"id":"5c0768207fb8217354de84d1","name": "Demon"}]}"
Response body: ""
System error msg: "Connection closed"    // error code is QNetworkReply::RemoteHostClosedError
```

Here, the output shows that one request has been sent and response body is empty (and response code also note 500 I think). However, Wireshark shows totally different thing for this request:

Server IP - `*.*.*.127`
Client IP - `*.*.*.128`

[image]

As I checked with the server, sending one request from this client causing the server to receive not only one, but different number of requests (from 1 to 4). In this example case, the server shows 4 requests have been received, respectively. Moreover, **in Wireshark, all the responses have expected bodies**.

I don't know why this is happening: Qt shows that it sent one request, but Wireshark and the server say 4 requests were sent. Long hours of debugging did not give any hint. I would appreciate any suggestions (solutions, debugging, directions)!

---

**JavaScript client.**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://192.168.101.127:1122/api/v1/replay/initReplay";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {          
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log('Status 200');
        console.log('Response\n');
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json);
    }

    if (xhr.status === 500) {
        console.log('Status 500');
        console.log('Response\n');
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json);
    }
};
var data = JSON.stringify({"game_id":"5c0768177fb8217354de84d0","objects":[{"id":"5c0768207fb8217354de84d1","name":"Demon"}]});
xhr.send(data);
```

*Output*:

[image]

I don't know why it printed three times but server received (always correctly) one request. And Wireshark proves this:

[image]

**Python client.**

```
import sys
import requests

post_fields = {
   "game_id":"5c0768177fb8217354de84d0",
   "objects":[
   {
      "id":"5c0768207fb8217354de84d1",
      "name":"Demon"
   }
   ]
}
link    = 'http://192.168.101.127:1122/api/v1/replay/initReplay'
s = requests.Session()
resp    = s.post(link,data=post_fields)
print(resp)
print(resp.content)
```

*Output*:

[image]

Python client worked ideally. Wireshark output:

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, what are the HTTP headers being sent? Since all three clients are using HTTP/1.0, I'd expect the all the connections to be closed after the reply... I would not be shocked to see Qt sending the request with the `Connection: Closed` header... That's where I'd look... PS the content-type in the response is not JSON

Comment: Clearly the headers in the logs are not set properly. Moreover please put a break point and check why you have four request being fired. I would first use simple json string without using QJSON and check if that works and also use setRawHeader and set content length. I hope its helpful.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the QNetworkReply signals instead of the QNetworkAccessManager one?

Comment: @ChrisMc, all the requests have `Connection: Keep-Alive` in the header.

Comment: @Ayak973, that was the first thing I have done, the same outcome